# "Ambrosiana manuscript" purporting to be Chayei Yehudah by Leon de Modena

Tags: manuscripts

Have any Orthodox Rabbis held or do hold that the "Ambrosiana manuscript" purporting to be "Chayei Yehudah" by Rabbi Leon de Modena is in fact that work by him, or is even his work altogether according to any Orthodox Rabbis?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Could you please edit your question with information about this manuscript and/or perhaps add a link or two for reference?

Comment: AFAIK, no orthodox rabbi (who’s even consulted the work altogether) has critically examined the ms. to arrive at any conclusion... that is, on record. The particular ms. has been treated most recently by Y. Dweck in his The Scandal of Kabbalah.